# Why is Polymorphism is needed when we have the keyword "auto" in C++

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

Correct me if i'm wrong, but the keyword "auto" can solve all the problems that polymorphism was invented to solve.

instead of declaring of virtual function func of class A, when we have Class B inheriting from it, we can just say that the function func is receiving auto param, and it will know what case to trigger.

What do i miss?

Comment: `Correct me if i'm wrong, but the keyword "auto" can solve all the problems that polymorphism was invented to solve.` You're wrong. Try for example `std::vector<auto*>`

Comment: You should list the problems that polymorphism (built-in runtime polymorphism in case of `virtual` functions being involved) was invented to solve and explain for each problem how it could be solved with `auto`. Your current *"just say that the function func is receiving auto param"* makes no sense.

Answer (score 10):

No, `auto` cannot solve *any* of those problems.

`auto` is a compile-time utility to deduce the type of a thing from the code that's around it. It is more closely related to templates (indeed, the `auto` in the parameter list of a lambda is implemented by a template!).

It has no knowledge of runtime states and cannot be used to perform virtual dispatch.

These are completely different concepts and your best bet would be to re-study what each one means.

Comment: Thank you. I was told that auto has runtime knowledge.

Comment: And `auto` variables use (slightly addended) template type deduction to tun into a concrete type.

Comment: @Or251 Tell whoever told you that to come here for a lesson ;)

Comment: @Or251 ... or, print the [current standard draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.auto.deduct#4) and hit said person hard with it. (For best effect not only print the relevant section but the whole draft ;)